# has_many вывести объекты при условии

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть две модели `Video`, `Thumb`

```
class Video
  has_many :thumbs
```

Как вывести все объекты `Video`, в которых thumbs.count == 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails **Counter Cache** http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column Поможет так же избежать большого количества запросов к БД.

```
Video.includes(:thumbs).where(:thumbs_count == 0)
```

Для уже существующих записей (из комментария от автора вопроса)

```
Video.find_each { |video| Video.reset_counters(video.id, :thumbs) }
```

Comment: добавил `counter_cache`.  Как уже у существующих записей прописать thumbs_count ? Делаю так, но все равно остаются нули:
Video.all.each do |video|
video.update(thumbs_count: video.thumbs.count)

Comment: нагуглил решение: Video.find_each { |video| Video.reset_counters(video.id, :thumbs) }